# Suppressing new windows opened by an executable called from within a flow in tcl

Tags: linux, shell, exec, tcl

I'm running a flow written in tcl, in Linux environment, that executes external executable files. One of those executables creates new windows during its run that pop up for a few seconds and then are destroyed. The information provided in those windows isn't needed, but they are annoying and interfere with normal work, while the flow runs in the background. The executable is called using `exec`:

```
set cmd "exec $KITE(SI_Exe)/run_SI_01_fast_touchstone.sh $KITE(MCRroot) $KITE(SI_config_file_name) "
puts "Running $cmd "
eval $cmd
```

Is there a way to suppress the popping up of those windows, similar to the way you can direct output from a program to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a linux system, that means you are most likely running X11. If that's true, and it's a sufficiently modern version, you could create a virtual frame buffer ([xvfb](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/Xvfb.1.html)) and then set the environment variable DISPLAY to use that for the display. That is the moral equivalent to /dev/null.